# How to set up an docker container into the kubevirt VM and enable an SSH access into that container from different network?

Tags: docker, networking, ssh, virtual-machine

Can I initiate a container within a kubevirt virtual machine (VM) and enable external SSH access to that container from outside the VM? We don't want to give an SSH access to the host VM, Users should be able to SSH into the container directly without doing SSH on VM.
Are there any approaches or best practices to implement this?